# In Windows 11, is there a way to always show all system tray icons in the taskbar?

Tags: icons, taskbar, system-tray, windows-11

In Windows 10, I was able to do this.

In Windows 11, I have to right click the task bar, choose task bar settings, choose Other system tray icons, and manually enable each one (see screenshots below).

The issue is, some applications seem to create new system tray icons and I have to repeat this process.

Is there a way to always display all system tray icons in the taskbar?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

type `explorer shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}` in cmd and check always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar option